# Plugin function to treat part of a WordPress URL as GET variable

Tags: wordpress, url, plugins

What I would like is for users to be able to

- access a page like *mywebsite.com/stores/my-custom-store* directly
- use *my-custom-store* as variable to show custom content on *mywebsite.com/stores/*

The trick here is that I want users to see the full URL in their browser (including *my-custom-store*), I don't want them to know they are being redirected to *mywebsite.com/stores/*

Basically, I would like to treat *my-custom-store* as a GET variable, but I would like to avoid doing that explicitly (so something like *mywebsite.com/stores/?store=my-custom-store*) because I need the URL to be as clean as possible, so that stores gan give out their own without difficulties.

I've tried to use something like this

```
if ( ! ( function_exists('identify_store') ) ) { function identify_store($vars){
    $vars[] = 'store';
    return $vars;
} }
add_filter('query_vars', 'identify_store', 0, 1);
if ( ! ( function_exists('add_custom_rewrite') ) ) { function add_custom_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^stores/([^/]*)/?','index.php?post_type=page&name=stores&store=$matches[1]','top');
} }
add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_rewrite' );
```

But this indeed removes the last part of the URL, which I wouldn't like to.